# PDO: Database reports an error: SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 2031

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

Hi can someone help me with this problem?

I have a stored procedure which is inserting a record in one table and updating some other tables. One record will be returned.
Called from the mysql workbench it works flawless.

When I use the code underneath (PHP using DBO) I get an error. I don't see the problem (probably staring blind).

```
   public function ChangePassword($email, $password, $newPassword )    {  

    try {
        $ip = getRealIpAddr();
        $stmt = $this->prepare("call STP_Set_Password(?, ?, ? ,? )");
        $stmt->bindvalue(1,$email,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindvalue(2,$password,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindvalue(3,$newPassword,PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->bindvalue(3,$ip,PDO::PARAM_STR);
    echo "call STP_Set_Password($email, $password, $newPassword, $ip)<br>";
        $stmt->execute();
        $itemlist = $stmt->fetchall();
        var_dump($itemlist);
        return $itemlist;
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo 'Database reports an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}
```

Passwords are hashes.
The code echo's the call to the stored procedure. This does run when I copy it to the mysql workbench.

Comment: I see 4 placeholders, but your `bindValue` looks wrong. You're binding the `3` two times.

Comment: That did the trick. I already had the feeling I overlooked something simple.